# How do I use two actions in a UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, subview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am working with two subviews.  Each will be unique and have it's own "action".

Subview 1 = User can drag around the view, rotate, and zoom it

Subview 2 = When user moves finger across their screen an image is added at each point their finger touches.

I have both of these completed by using UIPanGestureRecognizer.  My question is, how can I separate these two actions?  I want to be able to add one subview, do what is required, and then when I add the other subview, prevent the previous actions from occurring.

Here is what I have tried, this is done in my panGesture method:

```
 for (UIView * subview in imageView.subviews)
 {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        if (subview == _aImageView)
        {
            CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
            CGPoint imageViewPosition = _aImageView.center;
            imageViewPosition.x += translation.x;
            imageViewPosition.y += translation.y;

            _aImageView.center = imageViewPosition;
            [panRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
        }
        else if (subview == _bImageView)
        {
            currentTouch = [panRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

            CGFloat distance = [self distanceFromPoint:currentTouch ToPoint:prev_touchPoint];
            accumulatedDistance += distance;
            CGFloat fixedDistance = 60;

            if ([self distanceFromPoint:currentTouch ToPoint:prev_touchPoint] > fixedDistance)
            {
                [self addbImage];

                prev_touchPoint = currentTouch;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want different gesture recognition in two different views, put separate recognizers on each view.

Comment: Ok.  I have this done, but how do I only allow one gesture to be called?  So if I add aImageView as a subview first, then add bImageView as a subview, aImageView will still be added and it's gesture active.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you want to have your view controller own and manage gesture recognizers, e.g.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    self.panGesture.delegate = self;
    [self.viewX addGestureRecognizer:self.panGesture];
    // repeat with other recognisers...
}
```

Note that setting your controller as delegate of the gestureRecognizer is important: this enables you to handle the following delegate method from the view controller (which was the main question):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    // handle your logic, which gestureRecognizer should proceed...
    return NO;
}
```

The handler method is the same is this example, but you can set up your own handlers as you like:

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
     // handle gesture (usually sorted by state), e.g.
     // if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) { ... }
}
```